# Console stops printing in Safari's web inspector after automatic re-render

Tags: webpack, safari, next.js, web-inspector, safari-web-inspector

I encountered this problem, after a while of programming (see below ↓) the `console.log()` in my Safari (14.0.3 (16610.4.3.1.7)) inspector stops logging, in fact, it doesn't print anything including return values of statements.

[image]

My stack consists of NextJS (10.0.5) that I run through Vercel (21.3.3) using `vc dev`. It all runs on `webpack`.

I suspect it has to do something with fast refresh, because I believe, **in all cases it did happen after I modified something on the page** and the `webpack` rerendered. However it doesn't happen each time I make changes to my code, rather ocassionally. I can't clearly identify why.

Simply refreshing the page in Safari doesn't change anything, I have to go to a new tab so the `console.log` starts to print again.

- Where do you think I could search to resolve the bug?
- How can I reset seeing the logged values in web inspector without having to go to a new tab?

Comment: Have you tried Chrome?

Comment: Haha, sure. I've been using Chrome for a long time. Now I am using Safari and this is the problem I have encountered. Certainly, if there is no solution for this, I will be likely to change my web browser preference.